# How do I get Google Cloud load balancer to set a cookie via a socket.io server it's proxying?

Tags: session, cookies, socket.io, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I'm running a Google Cloud HTTPS load balancer in front of 2 Compute Engine VM instances that are each running a socket.io server on port 80. They work fine and are reachable from my HTML/JS socket.io client that I'm running locally.

I have set my Google Cloud load balancer to use Session Affinity with "Generated Cookie". According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#generated_cookie_affinity), this *should* set a cookie named `GCLB` on the client. The cookie never gets set in my client, why?

I think my issue might be that I'm not really serving the client through the load balancer (or on google at all), but serving it locally, once this is a real client it will sit on a CDN somewhere. I am using a hostname locally that is on the same domain name as the load balancer. Meaning, my socket.io html client is at `http://local.mydomain.com:8000/` and it connects to my socket.io server/load balancer which lives at `https://io.mydomain.com/` note: ssl on server only

Any ideas as to how I can get the cookie set, or do I need to handle this differently?